# Get the min value from array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm getting stuck on getting min value from array.
every time when I run it, the minimum value is still zero.
I know that the index has to go to minus one, but i just don't know how should I apply it on the code.

```
public class Class1 {
  int[] numbers = new int[99];

  public int Min() { // array gets de value thats on 0
    int Min = numbers[0];
    foreach(int number in numbers) { // if the number is smaller then 0.
      if (number < Min) { // zero is the new number
        Min = number;
      }

    }
    return Min;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can easily use with Linq,

Using System.Linq;

```
int min = numbers.Min();
```

Comment: Since there is already something in the core framework, why reinvent your own?

Comment: @Caramiriel Because this doesn't solve the problem the OP has. Besides, he likely needs to implement the functions himself for a CS exercise.

Comment: @Overv True. Although I think it would be easier to use `List<int>` in this case and use `.Min()`. This is just reinventing things that  already exist.

Comment: @Caramiriel I agree with you, but then the answer should have included that change.

Comment: @Caramiriel OP just stated that his assignment required using arrays.

Comment: @Overv i do agree he seems to look for an array solution, Min is a shortcut but it is necessary to know what happens behind scenes with time and space complexity

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you always calculate the minimum with all numbers, which includes zeroes for all the numbers you haven't added yet with the button. That's why your minimum always returns 0 right now unless you add 99 numbers. You need to change your `Min` function to:

```
public int Min() {
    int min = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        int number = numbers[i];

        if (number < min) {
            min = number;
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

As you can see, the function will now only calculate the minimum using the numbers you have added (with index below `index`) and not *all* numbers in the `numbers` array.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is your naming convention, you have a. Min variable and a Min method

Answer (score 0):

This is an agnostic implemetation showing what Linq Min does for an array of integers behind the scenes. It is also the most optimized algorithm for the OPs request.

**Notice:**

Time Complexity: O(n)
Auxiliary Space: O(1), as no extra space is used

```
   public  int Min(int[] numbers)
    {
        int min = numbers[0];
        
        foreach (int num in numbers)
        {
            // if the number (num) is smaller than current iteration (min) then it is the minimum.
            if (num < min)
            { 
                min = num;
            }
        }

        return min;
    }
```